# I Mac wireless keyboard return key not working

Tags: imac

My wireless keyboard return key isn't working, it randomly stopped with no damage to the keyboard and is not stuck down i.e still clicks, can you help please?

Comment: Perhaps dirt has got underneath - have you tried cleaning it?

Comment: If it does the same on another Mac and cleaning it is not an option for you to do yourself (having someone do it for you might cost more than a replacement) it is likely that the keyboard needs to be replaced.

Answer (score -1):

Accessibility can be a cause also.